# Initializing values in a vector

Tags: vector, vhdl

I have a `std_logic_vector` variable `RT` defined:

```
variable RT: std_logic_vector (127 downto 0);
```

I want to set the values `(127 downto 4)` to be all 0.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that. The most straightforward probably being

```
rt(127 downto 4) <= (others => '0');
```

Comment: This solution only applies if RT is a signal. The question asks for the initialization of variables.

Comment: @mfro Comment has been flagged for not being constructive/useful. I appreciate the help, even though it was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign a *initial* value to your variable you can do:

```
variable RT : std_logic_vector(127 downto 0) := (others => '0');
```

to assign all zero to RT.
If the first few positions of RT should have values different than '0' you can go for:

```
variable RT : std_logic_vector(127 downto 0) := (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '1',
    2 => '1',
    3 => '1',
    others => '0'
);
```

This will assign '1' to the first 4 positions and '0' to the rest.